# How to insert an image in this ListView that is used for inserting something else?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, listview

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I have to create a quiz engine application. I am using a ListView for inserting the questions under specific quiz.

I have the following database design:

```
QuizContent Table: ID, QuizID, QuestionID, AnswerID
Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, Description
Question Table: QuestionID, Question, QuestionOrder, AnswerExplanation
Answers Table: AnswerID, Answer
QuestionImage: ID, QuestionID, URL
```

What I want now is making the admin being able to embedd an image to any one of these questions. **How can I do that since I have two different tables in the database? One for the questions and one for the images as shown in the design above.** I have this design because not all of the questions will have images. Besides that, I may have two or three questions or more having the same image.

I know I should not post too much code or information, but I have to do it to make it clear:

```
<div align="center">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
            DataKeyNames="QuestionID" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListView2_SelectedIndexChanged">

            <EditItemTemplate>

                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/update24.png" ToolTip="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/cancel324.png" ToolTip="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionOrderTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("QuestionOrder") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerExplanationTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="UrlTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Url") %>' />
                     </td>--%>
                </tr>
            </EditItemTemplate>

            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table id="Table1" runat="server" 
                    style="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>

            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="InsertButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/add24.png" ToolTip="Add" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/clear24.png" ToolTip="Cancel"  runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionOrderTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("QuestionOrder") %>'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerExplanationTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                         <asp:FileUpload ID="ImageIDUploader" runat="server" size="10" />
                        </td>--%>
                </tr>

            </InsertItemTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="SelectButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/select.png" ToolTip="Select" runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionOrderLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("QuestionOrder") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerExplanationLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                            <a href='<%# Eval("URL") %>' target="_blank">
                                <asp:Label ID="ImageURLlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("URL") %>' />
                            </a>
                        </td>--%>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div ><table id="thetable" width="97%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; border:2px solid #003366; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color:#C6D7B5;">
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">...</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Question</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Question Order</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Answer Explanation</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Image (URL)</th>
                            </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody><tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr></tbody>
                    </table></div>     
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionOrderLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("QuestionOrder") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerExplanationLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                            <asp:Label ID="ImageURLlbl" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("URL") %>' />
                        </td>--%>
                </tr>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        </div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizSysDBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT     QuestionID, Question, QuestionOrder, AnswerExplanation
                            FROM         dbo.Question
                            WHERE     (QuestionID IN
                                                      (SELECT DISTINCT QuestionID
                                                        FROM          dbo.QuizContent
                                                        WHERE      (QuizID = @QuizID)))"

            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Question] WHERE [QuestionID] = @QuestionID" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Question] ([Question], [QuestionOrder], [AnswerExplanation]) VALUES (@Question, @QuestionOrder, @AnswerExplanation)" 


            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Question] SET [Question] = @Question, [QuestionOrder] = @QuestionOrder, [AnswerExplanation] = @AnswerExplanation WHERE [QuestionID] = @QuestionID">

                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Question" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionOrder" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="AnswerExplanation" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView1" Name="QuizID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Question" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionOrder" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="AnswerExplanation" Type="String" />
                </UpdateParameters>

            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView1" Name="QuizID" DefaultValue="0"
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**So how to do that?**

Answer (score 1):

Don't add the image in the same list view, but show a selection of existing images with an option to add another one that opens a popup with the list of all images and an option to upload a new one.

Create a view to combine questions and image:

```
CREATE VIEW QuestionsView AS
SELECT Question.*, QuestionImage.ID AS ImageID
FROM Question LEFT OUTER JOIN QuestionImage ON Question.QuestionID = QuestionImage.QuestionID
```

Use this view to select records for your ListView.

To show a DropDownList:

```
<td>
   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" DataSourceID="imagesDataSource" SelectedValue="<%# Bind("ImageID") %>" DataTextField="URL" DataValueField="ID" /> 
   <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="imagesDataSource" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM QuestionImage" />
</td>
```

Change your ListView data source to use a stored procedure for update that gets a parameter for each Bind use.

Add a link to open the images list popup. For the popup you can use one of the samples here: http://smashingspy.com/32-best-jquery-popup-window-dialog-box-example/

Comment: Since I am a new ASP.NET developer, could you please provide me with an example or code snippet?

Comment: Can I use SqlDataSource instead of ObjectDataSource? Also, Image object has a QuestionID not the opposite as you assumed, so is it OK?

Comment: Yes you can use sqldatasource. If I were you I'd add the ImageID column to the Questions table, but if you want to keep your database optimized create a view that will have this column

Comment: I did not get what you mean. Could you please how I will be able to do it using view?

Comment: Besides that, How I will add the Add option of the image in this ListView?

Comment: Thanks for your continuous help. Also, do you mean that I have to bind the whole listView to the View that you suggested? Sorry for asking too much but this is my first time to use view, so I don't know how to use them with the ListView. 

**Update:** please see my updated code to get an overall idea about how I am binding this ListView to the SqlDataSource

Comment: You don't have to use a view. You can edit your SqlDataSource query to the same query that I wrote to create the view.